# running function pyttsx3 text to speech causing application to close

Tags: python, text-to-speech, python-multithreading, pyttsx3

I am running text to speech function each time an Italian word is being
inserted into a listbox. Sometimes python script fails, after pronouncing
all the words. Sometimes after pronouncing all the words all the insertions
into listbox are done and nothing fails.
Since words are inserted into the listbox via a loop, one would expect
a word followed by its pronunciation, since the **parla_italiano()**
is called on each word. But it seems that the function is holding the
other python thread. I have never worked with threads yet. It there is
a way of releasing this function after pronouncing a word, and allowing
the word insertion into the listbox? I am using python 3.9 on windows10

```
def parla_italiano(phrase):
    import pyttsx3
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    it_voice_id = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_IT-IT_ELSA_11.0"
    engine.setProperty('voice', it_voice_id)
    engine.say(phrase)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

This is the error message:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: initialized
```